# Java FX: how to update ComboTableCell on change of another

Tags: javafx-2

im stuck into some problem, need guidance !
i have a TableView that has 2 ComboBoxTableCells, my requirement is to update the list in  combobox of 2nd cell on change of the first.

i have tried it the following way,no luck so far.

```
 public class Test{
    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty city;

    public Test(String name, String city){
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.city = new SimpleStringProperty(city);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.setValue(name); 
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city.get();
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city.setValue(city);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {return name;}
    public StringProperty cityProperty() {return city;}
}


    TableView _table= new TableView();
    final ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.add("name 1");
    list.add("name 2");
    list.add("name 3");
    list.add("name 4");

    final ObservableList list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list2.add("city 1");
    list2.add("city 2");
    list2.add("city 3");
    list2.add("city 4");

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("name"));
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list));

    firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Test, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Test, String> t) {
     ((Test) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setName(t.getNewValue());

                System.out.println(t.getTableColumn().getCellData(t.getTablePosition().getRow()));
```

i guess have to do something here, tried the following line to see the impact on the respective cell 

**list2.clear();** 
it updated data for the whole column i just want it to be updated for the respective cell only.

```
            }
        }
    );


    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("City");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("city"));
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list2));
    lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Test, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Test, String> t) {
                ((Test) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    );

    _table.setEditable(true);
    _table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol,lastNameCol);

    ObservableList listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    listItems.add(new Test("name 4", "city 2"));
    listItems.add(new Test("name 2", "city 3"));
    table.getTableView().setItems(listItems);
    _table.setItems(listItems);
```

**any help will be highly appreciated. thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky approach that I haven't tested:

1. Add a dummy (boolean?) **property** on the data items that you will use to communicate between firstNameCol and lastNameCol
2. In the onEditCommit handler for firstNameCol, change the value of the dummy property. Be sure it changes.
3. Have lastNameCol be a column for the dummy property. Register a cell factory for lastNameCol that returns a TableCell with an overriden updateItem() method (pseudo-code below)

   ```
   lastNameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback() {
       @Override
       public TableCell call(TableColumn col) {
           return new TableCell() {
               @Override
               public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                   if (!empty) {
                       // Don't care about the value of item
                       // Just look up the value of firstNameCol using
                       // getTablePosition(), then create and populate
                       // a ComboBox with the appropriate items and set
                       // it as the graphic for this cell via this.setGraphic()
                       // Add handler to ComboBox control to update data item when
                       // selection changes
                   }                                                
               }
           };
       }
   });
   ```